# How to use mkdtemp in solaris

Tags: c++, qt5, std, solaris

I am currently trying to build a 3rd party project (qt 5.0.1) for Solaris and am currently stuck with the following error:

```
io/qtemporarydir.cpp: In member function 'void QTemporaryDirPrivate::create(const QString&)':
io/qtemporarydir.cpp:150:30: error: 'mkdtemp' was not declared in this scope
gmake[3]: *** [.obj/release-shared/qtemporarydir.o] Error 1
```

From what I have found out, mkdtemp should be found in stdlib.h which is in /usr/include. However looking in stdlib.h on my solaris system it soes not define the mkdtemp method.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this? (Or how I can compile Qt for Solaris...)

Comment: cf. my related question and answer regarding building Qt 5.2 under Solaris: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20879715/427158

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since found that there was an additional function in the Qt source which replaced mkdtemp for systems which did not define it themselves. However it was wrapped in an #ifdef statement which did not account for Solaris builds. Uncommenting the #ifdef wrapper fixed that buil