# How to build Qt 5.2 on Solaris 10?

Tags: solaris, qt5

The Qt page does not list pre-compiled Qt 5 packages for Solaris. Searching around, it does not seem to be included in the popular package repository OpenCSW, either. Some google hits suggest that building Qt 5 under Solaris involves some work under Solaris 10.

Thus my question: How to build Qt 5.2 under Solaris 10?

Answer (score 10):

Basically it is:

```
cd qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.0
./configure -prefix $MY_PREFIX -opensource -confirm-license -nomake tests \
    -R /opt/csw/lib/64 -R /opt/csw/X11/lib/64 -qt-xcb -platform solaris-g++-64 \
    -verbose
gmake -j16
gmake -j16 install
```

plus some adjustments because Qt 5 does not seem to be used on
Solaris much, yet.

### Adjustments

#### Obtain the source

```
wget http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.0/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.0.tar.gz
md5sum qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.0.tar.gz
228b6384dfd7272de00fd8b2c144fecd  qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.0.tar.gz
```

If the system does not habe `md5sum` you can use `openssl md5 filename` instead.

#### Install dependencies

I recommend to use [OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/) because we need some dependencies to build Qt. The most important ones are:

```
CSWlibxcbdevel
CSWlibicu-dev    # soft-dependency
CSWgcc4g++
CSWgmake
```

I suggest to use GCC to compile Qt. I am not aware of any advantages using the C++ compiler from Solaris Studio. On the contrary, the level of C++/STL support of this compiler may be not sufficient for a lot of use cases.

#### Setup environment

Make sure that you environment is clean. That means that `/opt/csw/bin` comes first and no LD_LIBRAYR_PATH* variables are set.

To simplify things it is probably a good idea that some directories are removed from `PATH`. For example such that no `cc`, `CC` commands from a Solaris Studio installation are accidentally picked up (e.g. during the compile of a bundled 3rd party component.

#### Adjust the specs

The software under `/usr/sfw` is just too outdated. `/opt/csw` from [OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/) is a better replacement. Then the X-Open version is not sufficient for some used system functions.

```
--- a/qtbase/mkspecs/solaris-g++-64/qmake.conf
+++ b/qtbase/mkspecs/solaris-g++-64/qmake.conf
@@ -35,7 +35,7 @@ QMAKE_LEX               = flex
 QMAKE_LEXFLAGS          =
 QMAKE_YACC              = yacc
 QMAKE_YACCFLAGS         = -d
-QMAKE_CFLAGS            = -m64 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D__EXTENSIONS__
+QMAKE_CFLAGS            = -m64 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D__EXTENSIONS__
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEPS       = -M
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON    = -Wall -W
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_OFF   = -w
@@ -58,8 +58,8 @@ QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_STATIC_LIB = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_STATIC_LIB
 QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_YACC     = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_YACC
 QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_THREAD   = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_THREAD

-QMAKE_INCDIR            = /usr/sfw/include
-QMAKE_LIBDIR            = /usr/sfw/lib/64
+QMAKE_INCDIR            = /opt/csw/include /opt/csw/X11/include
+QMAKE_LIBDIR            = /opt/csw/lib/64 /opt/csw/X11/lib/64
 QMAKE_INCDIR_X11        = /usr/openwin/include
 QMAKE_LIBDIR_X11        = /usr/openwin/lib/64
 QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL     = /usr/openwin/include
```

#### Fix the shell

Solaris comes with a `/bin/sh` that violates POSIX to an extend such
that Qt's configure scripts and even shell-code in qmake-generated
code fails.

POSIX does not specify that `/bin/sh` has to be conforming it just specifies that the system must have a conforming shell available 'somewhere'. On Solaris it is e.g. under `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`. The portable way  to get a conforming shell is to search for it in the directories returned by `getconf CS_PATH` ...

Anyways, my choice for Solaris is to just use `/usr/bin/bash`:

Anyways, my choice for Solaris is to just use `/usr/bin/bash`:

```
--- a/configure
+++ b/configure
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-#! /bin/sh
+#!/usr/bin/bash
 #############################################################################
 ##
 ## Copyright (C) 2012 Digia Plc and/or its subsidiary(-ies).
--- a/qtbase/configure
+++ b/qtbase/configure
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-#!/bin/sh
+#!/usr/bin/bash
 #############################################################################
 ##
 ## Copyright (C) 2013 Digia Plc and/or its subsidiary(-ies).
@@ -6892,7 +6892,7 @@ fi'`
     echo "$CONFIG_STATUS" | grep '\-confirm\-license' >/dev/null 2>&1 || CONFIG_STATUS="$CONFIG_STATUS -confirm-license"

     [ -f "$outpath/config.status" ] && rm -f "$outpath/config.status"
-    echo "#!/bin/sh" > "$outpath/config.status"
+    echo "#!/usr/bin/bash" > "$outpath/config.status"
     [ -n "$PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR" ] && \
         echo "export PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=$PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR" >> "$outpath/config.status"
     [ -n "$PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR" ] && \
--- a/qtbase/qmake/generators/makefile.cpp
+++ b/qtbase/qmake/generators/makefile.cpp
@@ -2306,6 +2306,10 @@ MakefileGenerator::writeHeader(QTextStream &t)
     if (ofile.lastIndexOf(Option::dir_sep) != -1)
         ofile.remove(0, ofile.lastIndexOf(Option::dir_sep) +1);
     t << "MAKEFILE      = " << ofile << endl << endl;
+
+    t << "# custom mod because Solaris /bin/sh is such a standard-violating choice\n"
+      << "#   - gs, 2013-12-23" << endl;
+    t << "SHELL         = /usr/bin/bash" << endl << endl;
 }

 QList<MakefileGenerator::SubTarget*>
```

#### Fix the ICU test

Solaris 10 comes with an outdated libicu - which is missing features Qt 5 needs. Thus, we simply extend the icu-test. Then either no ICU-support is build or proper one in case we install a recent libicu e.g. via OpenCSW.

```
--- a/qtbase/config.tests/unix/icu/icu.cpp
+++ b/qtbase/config.tests/unix/icu/icu.cpp
@@ -43,6 +43,16 @@
 #include <unicode/ucol.h>
 #include <unicode/ustring.h>

+// for testing if ucal_clone is there (i.e. if we have libicu >= 4.0)
+#include <unicode/ucal.h>
+
+static UCalendar *ucp(UCalendar *i)
+{
+    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
+    UCalendar *r = ucal_clone(i, &status);
+    return r;
+}
+
 int main(int, char **)
 {
     UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
@@ -50,5 +60,10 @@ int main(int, char **)
     if (U_FAILURE(status))
         return 0;
     ucol_close(collator);
+
+    UCalendar *cal = ucal_open(0, -1, "C", UCAL_GREGORIAN, &status);
+    UCalendar *x = ucp(cal);
+    ucal_close(x);
+
     return 0;
 }
```

#### Fix bundled pcre

Perhaps alternatively one can install a libpcre via OpenCSW.

```
--- a/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre/pcre_compile.c
+++ b/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre/pcre_compile.c
@@ -66,6 +66,8 @@ COMPILE_PCREx macro will already be appropriately set. */
 #endif


+#include <stdint.h>
+
 /* Macro for setting individual bits in class bitmaps. */

 #define SETBIT(a,b) a[(b)/8] |= (1 << ((b)&7))
```

#### Fix sha3

At least on Solaris 10/Sparc the functions `fromBytesToWord` and `fromWordtoBytes` are used by the code, thus:

```
--- a/qtbase/src/3rdparty/sha3/KeccakF-1600-opt64.c
+++ b/qtbase/src/3rdparty/sha3/KeccakF-1600-opt64.c
@@ -324,7 +324,7 @@ static void KeccakPermutation(unsigned char *state)
     KeccakPermutationOnWords((UINT64*)state);
 }

-#if 0 // Unused in the Qt configuration
+#if 1 // Unused in the Qt configuration
 static void fromBytesToWord(UINT64 *word, const UINT8 *bytes)
 {
     unsigned int i;
@@ -445,7 +445,7 @@ static void KeccakAbsorb(unsigned char *state, const unsigned char *data, unsign
 #endif
 }

-#if 0 // Unused in the Qt configuration
+#if 1 // Unused in the Qt configuration
 static void fromWordToBytes(UINT8 *bytes, const UINT64 word)
 {
     unsigned int i;
```

#### Include/type/usage fixes

The `uname()` function is activated via a CPP construct on Solaris
and is declared in that header:

```
--- a/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfileselector.cpp
+++ b/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfileselector.cpp
@@ -51,6 +51,8 @@
 #include <QtCore/QLocale>
 #include <QtCore/QDebug>

+#include <sys/utsname.h>
+
 QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

 //Environment variable to allow tooling full control of file selectors
```

Under Solaris parent is unused in that code-path and the code gets compiled with `-Werror` ...

```
--- a/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfilesystemwatcher.cpp
+++ b/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfilesystemwatcher.cpp
@@ -77,6 +77,7 @@ QFileSystemWatcherEngine *QFileSystemWatcherPrivate::createNativeEngine(QObject
 #elif defined(Q_OS_FREEBSD) || defined(Q_OS_MAC)
     return QKqueueFileSystemWatcherEngine::create(parent);
 #else
+    (void)parent;
     return 0;
 #endif
 }
```

Under Solaris `uid_t` has an 'unexpected' sign (-> Werror). Casting it to `ssize_t` should be a portable and safe choice:

```
--- a/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qstandardpaths_unix.cpp
+++ b/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qstandardpaths_unix.cpp
@@ -132,7 +132,7 @@ QString QStandardPaths::writableLocation(StandardLocation type)
         }
         // "The directory MUST be owned by the user"
         QFileInfo fileInfo(xdgRuntimeDir);
-        if (fileInfo.ownerId() != myUid) {
+        if (fileInfo.ownerId() != ssize_t(myUid)) {
             qWarning("QStandardPaths: wrong ownership on runtime directory %s, %d instead of %d", qPrintable(xdgRuntimeDir),
                      fileInfo.ownerId(), myUid);
             return QString();
```

Similar issue with threading code (Werror because of sign-mismatch in pointer cast). Casting to size_t should be a portable safe choice:

```
--- a/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthread_unix.cpp
+++ b/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthread_unix.cpp
@@ -231,7 +231,7 @@ QThreadData *QThreadData::current()
         }
         data->deref();
         data->isAdopted = true;
-        data->threadId = (Qt::HANDLE)pthread_self();
+        data->threadId = (Qt::HANDLE)((size_t)pthread_self());
         if (!QCoreApplicationPrivate::theMainThread)
             QCoreApplicationPrivate::theMainThread = data->thread;
     }
@@ -314,7 +314,7 @@ void *QThreadPrivate::start(void *arg)
             thr->d_func()->setPriority(QThread::Priority(thr->d_func()->priority & ~ThreadPriorityResetFlag));
         }

-        data->threadId = (Qt::HANDLE)pthread_self();
+        data->threadId = (Qt::HANDLE)((size_t)pthread_self());
         set_thread_data(data);

         data->ref();
@@ -393,7 +393,7 @@ void QThreadPrivate::finish(void *arg)
 Qt::HANDLE QThread::currentThreadId() Q_DECL_NOTHROW
 {
     // requires a C cast here otherwise we run into trouble on AIX
-    return (Qt::HANDLE)pthread_self();
+    return (Qt::HANDLE)((size_t)pthread_self());
 }

 #if defined(QT_LINUXBASE) && !defined(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)
```

The struct `in_addr` has a struct as first attribute on Solaris, thus gives a warning with GCC when initializing with `{0}` - thus, yields an error during Qt-compile:

```
--- a/qtbase/src/network/socket/qnativesocketengine_unix.cpp
+++ b/qtbase/src/network/socket/qnativesocketengine_unix.cpp
@@ -63,6 +63,7 @@
 #endif

 #include <netinet/tcp.h>
+#include <string.h>

 QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

@@ -737,7 +738,8 @@ QNetworkInterface QNativeSocketEnginePrivate::nativeMulticastInterface() const
         return QNetworkInterface::interfaceFromIndex(v);
     }

-    struct in_addr v = { 0 };
+    struct in_addr v;
+    memset(&v, 0, sizeof(struct in_addr));
     QT_SOCKOPTLEN_T sizeofv = sizeof(v);
     if (::getsockopt(socketDescriptor, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, &v, &sizeofv) == -1)
         return QNetworkInterface();
```

The header comment of `X11/Xutil.h` lists `X11/Xutil.h` as dependency, and indeed, without that include some declarations are missing under Solaris.

```
--- a/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/qxcbmime.cpp
+++ b/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/qxcbmime.cpp
@@ -46,6 +46,7 @@
 #include <QtCore/QBuffer>
 #include <qdebug.h>

+#include <X11/Xlib.h>
 #include <X11/Xutil.h>

 #undef XCB_ATOM_STRING
```

The `X11/extensions/XIproto.h` is not C++-safe under Solaris. That means it contains struct members names `class`. Fortunately, the header does not seem to be used in that code.

```
--- a/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/qxcbxsettings.cpp
+++ b/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/qxcbxsettings.cpp
@@ -43,7 +43,7 @@

 #include <QtCore/QByteArray>

-#include <X11/extensions/XIproto.h>
+//#include <X11/extensions/XIproto.h>

 QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
 /* Implementation of http://standards.freedesktop.org/xsettings-spec/xsettings-0.5.html */
```

The `pow()` function has some overloads as specified in the C++ standard which introduce ambiguities under Solaris. Fixing the types like this should be portable and safe:

```
--- a/qtdeclarative/src/qml/jsruntime/qv4globalobject.cpp
+++ b/qtdeclarative/src/qml/jsruntime/qv4globalobject.cpp
@@ -534,7 +534,7 @@ ReturnedValue GlobalFunctions::method_parseInt(CallContext *ctx)
     }

     if (overflow) {
-        double result = (double) v_overflow * pow(R, overflow_digit_count);
+        double result = (double) v_overflow * pow(double(R), int(overflow_digit_count));
         result += v;
         return Encode(sign * result);
     } else {
```

Under Solaris, alloca needs another header:

```
--- a/qtdeclarative/src/qml/jsruntime/qv4stringobject.cpp
+++ b/qtdeclarative/src/qml/jsruntime/qv4stringobject.cpp
@@ -73,6 +73,11 @@
 #  include <windows.h>
 #endif

+
+#if OS(SOLARIS)
+#include <alloca.h>
+#endif
+
 using namespace QV4;

 DEFINE_MANAGED_VTABLE(StringObject);
```

#### Fix deep mkdir

Qt does a 'deep' `mkdir()` (e.g. something like `mkdir -p` for e.g. creating a directory hierarchy, e.g. `~/.config/company/product`. The Qt 5.2 algorithm may abort too soon on Solaris if an existing directory is located inside a non-writable NFS mounted parent - because in that case Solaris returns `EACCESS` instead of `EEXIST`.

```
--- a/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfilesystemengine_unix.cpp
+++ b/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfilesystemengine_unix.cpp
@@ -579,6 +579,11 @@ bool QFileSystemEngine::createDirectory(const QFileSystemEntry &entry, bool crea
                         // on the QNet mountpoint returns successfully and reports S_IFDIR.
                         || errno == ENOENT
 #endif
+#if defined(Q_OS_SOLARIS)
+                        // On Solaris 10, mkdir returns EACCESS on a directory which exists
+                        // inside an NFS mount ...
+                        || errno == EACCES
+#endif
                     ) {
                         QT_STATBUF st;
                         if (QT_STAT(chunk.constData(), &st) == 0 && (st.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR)
```

#### Temporary files

Solaris also does not have `mkdtemp()`:

```
--- a/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qtemporarydir.cpp
+++ b/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qtemporarydir.cpp
@@ -52,7 +52,7 @@
 #endif

 #include <stdlib.h> // mkdtemp
-#if defined(Q_OS_QNX) || defined(Q_OS_WIN) || defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
+#if defined(Q_OS_QNX) || defined(Q_OS_WIN) || defined(Q_OS_ANDROID) || defined(Q_OS_SOLARIS)
 #include <private/qfilesystemengine_p.h>
 #endif

@@ -96,7 +96,7 @@ static QString defaultTemplateName()

 static char *q_mkdtemp(char *templateName)
 {
-#if defined(Q_OS_QNX ) || defined(Q_OS_WIN) || defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
+#if defined(Q_OS_QNX ) || defined(Q_OS_WIN) || defined(Q_OS_ANDROID) || defined(Q_OS_SOLARIS)
     static const char letters[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

     const size_t length = strlen(templateName);
```

#### Pthreads

Solaris does not have `pthread_get_stacksize_np` (the `_np` suffix stands for non-portable).

Solaris has another function for getting stack-address/size values. My attempt:

```
--- a/qtdeclarative/src/qml/jsruntime/qv4engine.cpp
+++ b/qtdeclarative/src/qml/jsruntime/qv4engine.cpp
@@ -73,6 +73,11 @@
 #include "qv4isel_moth_p.h"

 #if USE(PTHREADS)
+
+#if OS(SOLARIS)
+#include <thread.h>
+#endif
+
 #  include <pthread.h>
 #endif

@@ -103,6 +108,11 @@ quintptr getStackLimit()
     } else
         size = pthread_get_stacksize_np(thread_self);
     stackLimit -= size;
+#  elif OS(SOLARIS)
+    stack_t ss;
+    int r = thr_stksegment(&ss);
+    (void)r;
+    stackLimit = reinterpret_cast<quintptr>(ss.ss_sp);
 #  else
     void* stackBottom = 0;
     pthread_attr_t attr;


--- a/qtdeclarative/src/qml/jsruntime/qv4mm.cpp
+++ b/qtdeclarative/src/qml/jsruntime/qv4mm.cpp
@@ -67,6 +67,11 @@
 #include <sys/storage.h>   // __tls()
 #endif

+#if OS(SOLARIS)
+#include <thread.h>
+#include <pthread.h>
+#endif
+
 QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

 using namespace QV4;
@@ -218,6 +223,11 @@ MemoryManager::MemoryManager()
 #  if OS(DARWIN)
     void *st = pthread_get_stackaddr_np(pthread_self());
     m_d->stackTop = static_cast<quintptr *>(st);
+#  elif OS(SOLARIS)
+    stack_t ss;
+    int r = thr_stksegment(&ss);
+    (void)r;
+    m_d->stackTop = static_cast<quintptr *>(ss.ss_sp) + ss.ss_size/sizeof(quintptr);
 #  else
     void* stackBottom = 0;
     pthread_attr_t attr;
```

I recommend a careful review of that code because my Qt-code does not use that Qt-module, thus, I did not test it much.

#### XKB extension

Qt 5 seems to heavily rely on the XKB extension. It seems that you can't build Qt 5 without XKB support. It comes bundled with xkbcommon.

First, make sure that it finds the right XKB database. Otherwise keyboard input does not work at all in your Qt programs!

Solaris does not have the default value `/usr/share/X11/xkb`. It has instead:

```
/usr/X11/lib/X11/xkb
/usr/openwin/lib/X11/xkb
```

But I havn't had luck with those - xkbcommon simply could not find any components with those.

I ended up with copying `/usr/share/X11/xkb` from a cygwin distribution to a custom path and configuring that as XKB database.

Whatever XKB you choose you have to configure it:

```
--- a/qtbase/src/3rdparty/xkbcommon.pri
+++ b/qtbase/src/3rdparty/xkbcommon.pri
@@ -1,7 +1,12 @@
 QMAKE_CFLAGS += -std=gnu99 -w
 INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/xkbcommon $$PWD/xkbcommon/src $$PWD/xkbcommon/src/xkbcomp

+solaris-g++-64 {
+DEFINES += DFLT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT='\\"/MY/XKB/CHOICE\\"'
+} else {
 DEFINES += DFLT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT='\\"/usr/share/X11/xkb\\"'
+}

 ### RMLVO names can be overwritten with environmental variables (See libxkbcommon documentation)
 DEFINES += DEFAULT_XKB_RULES='\\"evdev\\"'
```

For testing it also make sense to check for NULL values in error message parameters:

```
--- a/qtbase/src/3rdparty/xkbcommon/src/xkbcomp/xkbcomp.c
+++ b/qtbase/src/3rdparty/xkbcommon/src/xkbcomp/xkbcomp.c
@@ -68,8 +68,11 @@ text_v1_keymap_new_from_names(struct xkb_keymap *keymap,
         log_err(keymap->ctx,
                 "Couldn't look up rules '%s', model '%s', layout '%s', "
                 "variant '%s', options '%s'\n",
-                rmlvo->rules, rmlvo->model, rmlvo->layout, rmlvo->variant,
-                rmlvo->options);
+                rmlvo->rules, rmlvo->model,
+                rmlvo->layout ? rmlvo->layout : "(NULL)",
+                rmlvo->variant ? rmlvo->variant : "(NULL)",
+                rmlvo->options ? rmlvo->options : "(NULL)"
+                );
         return false;
     }
```

There is also the possibility that your XServer does not even support the XKB extension. Again, I don't know if Qt 5 can be configured with disabled-XKB-support under X.

You can check your X-server like this:

```
xprop -root | grep xkb
```

Or call a random xkb-program, e.g.:

```
xkbvleds
```

Such call should not result in an error like:

```
Fatal Error: Server doesn't support a compatible XKB
```

In case your XServer does not have XKB - Qt programs are likely to segfault. Qt does not seem to really check for XKB support. It does not seem to have a fallback mechanism when XKB is not usable.

#### Examples

Some examples fail because of module quick not being found:

```
--- a/qtconnectivity/examples/bluetooth/scanner/scanner.pro
+++ b/qtconnectivity/examples/bluetooth/scanner/scanner.pro
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-QT = core bluetooth quick
+QT = core bluetooth # quick
 SOURCES += qmlscanner.cpp

 TARGET = qml_scanner
diff --git a/qtconnectivity/examples/nfc/poster/poster.pro b/qtconnectivity/examples/nfc/poster/poster.pro
index d108b2a..d0d0659 100644
--- a/qtconnectivity/examples/nfc/poster/poster.pro
+++ b/qtconnectivity/examples/nfc/poster/poster.pro
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-QT += qml quick network nfc widgets
+QT += qml network nfc widgets # quick

 SOURCES += \
     qmlposter.cpp
```

They are also built without.

#### make install

A `gmake install` surprisingly triggers the compilation of several modules not yet compiled. Thus it make sense to execute it in parallel:

```
$ gmake -j16 install
```

(assuming that your system has a sufficient number of cores)

#### QtHelp

The bundled QtHelp module is not build/installed with the main compile/install steps.

To fix that:

```
cd qttools
PATH=$MY_PREFIX/bin:$PATH qmake
gmake
gmake install
```

### Open issues

- when using a remote Cygwin-X connection some colors are weird - e.g. the standard widget-gray is some light-light-blue - any ideas where to start to look for that?
- QtSVG is successfully built but displaying a small SVG (e.g. inside a QLabel) hangs the dialog - a `truss -u :` shows function calls inside libm/QtWidget - perhaps the system is just way too slow and/or some code-path is not optimized on Solaris/in combination with a X-forwarding over ssh
- a Qt-Program prints on startup: `Qt Warning: Could not find a location of the system's Compose files. Consider setting the QTCOMPOSE environment variable.` - no idea what feature this is about

### Conclusion

With those adjustments 'normal' Qt programs (without QtSvg) compile
and run fine under Solaris 10.

Comment: How about contributing the above fixes to Qt? Or at least opening bug reports so things don't go unnoticed. Note that some of those are already fixed or have fixes pending, f.i. [cea101bd](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/commit/cea101bd) solved the SHA3 code build, [this](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,74466) solves QFileSelector's issue, etc.

Comment: @peppe, yes, I'll do some rtfm on Qt's code review process and then submit the missing pieces. For now there is https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-35905 with some initial review comments.

Comment: Many of these issues are fixed in Solaris 11, which is 7 years newer than Solaris 10.